# How to prevent Mobile Safari from blowing up fonts?

Tags: ios, css, mobile-safari

Mobile Safari is making *some* fonts bigger when I am rotating the phone.

That's is driving me crazy and I can't get rid of this behavior.

Read about `-webkit-text-adjust-size` and tried it with all possible combinations but it doesn't seem to work. Is there anything new added in iOS9?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the META Viewport tag?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: That is set as well. I wouldn't notice it but it seems too obvious when one text is like twice as big as than the other. Say near the menu.

Comment: Are you able to post a code sample of HTML and CSS on codepen or JSfiddle? I can do some more troubleshooting then.